# Javascript scroll to bottom generating duplicate requests

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I have the following javascript code used to create a kind of infinite scroll UI. The problem is when I scroll with the mouse wheel it will generate several requests.

sample [HERE](http://uat.bb10backgrounds.com/jmastest2.html)

```
var canLoad = true;

$(window).scroll(function()
{ 
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && canLoad)
    {
    canLoad = false;
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "/loadmore.html",
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
            var $html = $(html);
            $html.imagesLoaded(function() {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                $("#container").masonry('appended', $html, true);
            }).appendTo($("#container"));
            }else
            {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more backgrounds to show.</center>');
            }
        }
        });
        canLoad = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option would be to use a timer within your `scroll` function, and cancel it before each request:

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function()
{
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function()
    {
        // Run whatever code you want here...
    }, 300);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FcxSL/

Answer (score 0):

i read your question wrong,

heres what you need to do,
 make sure when you ajax content in you give an an ajaxed div an id . then you put an if statment

check to see if that element exists if it does it will not do the post request again, if its not in the dom it will do the request.